# Tracking Completed Tasks in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm writing an application in Java which uses ExecutorService for running multiple threads.

I wish to submit multiple tasks (thousands at a time) to the Executor as Callables and when done, retrieve their result. The way I'm approaching this is each time I call submit() function, I get a Future which I store in an ArrayList. Later I pass the List to a thread which keeps iterating over it, calling future.get() function with a timeout to see if the task completed. is this the right approach or is to too inefficient?

EDIT --- More info ---
Another problem is that each Callable takes different amount of processing time. So if I simply take the first element out of the List and call get() on it, it will block while results of others may become available and the program will not know. That is why I need to keep iterating with timeouts.

thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend that you consider the ListenableFuture utilities in the Guava library: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the call to Future.get will block until the answer is available.  So you don't need another thread to iterate over the array list.

See here https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6

Comment: Understood. But I submit thousands of tasks to the ExecutorService in burst. So I need to store the Futures somewhere for future reference. While I'm blocked on the first Callable, another might have been completed and I won't know. Any ideas?

Comment: Storing them in the list is fine.  You will get to the one that has finished as soon as the one that is blocked is complete.

Comment: Storing them in the list is fine.  You will get to the one that has finished as soon as the one that is blocked is complete. If you need to be notified of every single completion as and when it happend e.g. to update a UI then in general you should use a notification mechanism rather than polling. I think Future.get is too generic a mechanism for that purpose.

Comment: But what if I want to get to the one that completed first? Get tasks in the order they complete. I'm looking into CompletionService as suggested by the other answer and it is making sense.

Comment: CompletionService definitely like the way to go indeed :)

Comment: Lets see if there are any other suggestions :) Also concerned about the Performance of CompletionService

Comment: BTW, I would totally +1 your answer just for your help. Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't aware of completion service - but reading the docs it looks like it would do what you want.  You could do it yourself by having each call method somehow notify that it has finished, but it looks like completion service would be a better solution than the way you were doing it originally, and you would get each task as it completed.

Answer (score 6):

> > is this the right approach or is to too inefficient?

This is not the correct approach per se. You are needlessly iterating over `ArrayList` checking for task completion.

This is very simple: Just use: [CompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html). You can easily wrap your existing executor into it. From JavaDocs:

> Producers submit tasks for execution. Consumers take completed tasks
>   and process their results in the order they complete.

In essence, `CompletionService` provides a way to get the result back simply by calling `take()`. It is a blocking function and the caller will block until the results are available.

---